# Can I mix copy and encode in one operation to have an accurate and fast cut?

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried many video cutters powered by ffmpeg, and they all have the same issue: Fast custting is not accurate without re-encoding.
I tried many solution in my own app, but nothing works as I need.
So, I have this idea to fix this issue:
suppose I want to generate a new video that doesn't contain the chuck starts at t1 to t2. I want ffmpeg to do this to divide the segment (t1, t2) to 3 parts:

1. a part (t1-x, t1+y), which is a complete encoded block that should be re-encoded to be able to copy the part (t1, y) precisely.
2. a part (t2-z, t3+w), which is a complete encoded block that should be re-encoded to be able to copy the part (z, t2) precisely.
3. a middle part (y, z) which contains complete encoded blocks, where it can be copied as is.

Then join the 3 parts resulted from the above steps.
Note that the first two parts are expected to be small (and one of them or both can be zero length), so, the re-encoding process will be fast. This will make us able to have exact cuts with slightly slower operation but still super faster than re-encoding the full video. It can be even faster if we can do multiple cuts with one command, so we traverse the frames once.

So, can I do that today with ffmpeg?
Or, can ffmpeg support it soon?
I hope if someone can apply this, and tell us how, or mention some of the ffmpeg team, or deliver it to them anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Ffmpeg supports key-frame cutting using the `ss` parameter, but its position is
all-important.

Example for key-frame seeking:

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i input_vid.mp4 -t 60 -c copy output_clip.mp4
```

Example for all-frame seeking:

```
ffmpeg -i input_vid.mp4 -ss 30 -t 60 -c copy output_clip.mp4
```

The `-copy` parameter here is important since it causes
[Stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy).
In some cases, you would need to add the parameter `-noaccurate_seek`.

For more information see:

- [Cutting Videos with FFmpeg](http://www.markbuckler.com/post/cutting-ffmpeg/)
- [Seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)
- [Video seeking and cutting sections - 2020](https://www.bogotobogo.com/FFMpeg/ffmpeg_seeking_ss_option_cutting_section_video_image.php)

---

Most videos use codecs which perform temporal compression, so a specified cutpoint may rely on frames before (and after) that cutpoint to be correctly decoded. So, when you use ffmpeg to trim videos with the `copy` mode, ffmpeg has to include all frames before and after the trimmed segment which are needed to decode the segment correctly. This can result in a starting black segment.

To still use copy mode but avoid the black segment, you need to set
the switch `-avoid_negative_ts`.

Comment: How can this solve the issue I explained?

Comment: I think we need a new command to do it. somthing like:

Comment: I may misunderstand your problem, but it seems to me that the algorithm you describe is already the way ffmpeg works with all-frame seeking and the `-copy` option.

Comment: cutting videos using Copy is not accurate. This needs to re-encode which takes too long. So, I want to mix the two operations to re-encode just small parts around the cut positions.

Comment: I tried to do this myself by exsisting commands, but copying at keyframees still have issues (delayed sound or start with blank images). If I can cut at keyframes without issues, I can apply the algorithm myself.

Comment: So, what is the exact keyframe to cut at without any issues? How the copy command decide the right time to cut?

Comment: Using all-frame seeking should be exact with no mismatched video/audio. Please add the command you use to your post using [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1570180/edit).

Comment: When I use this command to fragment the video: `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -acodec copy -f segment -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 OUTPUT%d.mp4 `

each fragment I get is accurate with no issues. I want to get the same result when I copy a part starting from Jeyframe1 to Keyframe2. What is the perfect command to do that?

Comment: I am using `ffmpeg -i <SrcFile> -ss <start> -t <duration> -c copy   <DstFile>"` and it results in a black period at start of the video, even when <start> is the time of a keyframe.

Comment: I added more info to the answer.

Comment: > ffmpeg has to include all frames before and after the trimmed segment which are needed to decode the segment correctly.

This is why I suggested my algorithm, to devide the segment to 3 parts:
1. a parts that contains the leading frames until the end of the encoded block: this should be re-encoded to be able to cut at the desired point. 
2. a parts that contains the lagging frames until the end of the encoded block: this also should be re-encoded to be able to cut at the desired point.
3. a middle part which contains complete encoded blocks, where it can be copied as is.

Comment: the first two parts are expected to be small (and one of them or both can be zero length), so, the re-encoding process will be fast. This will make us able to have exact cuts with slightly slower operation. it can be faster if we can do multiple cuts with one command, so we traverse the frames once.
I hope if someone can mansion some of the ffmpeg team, or deliver it to them.
thanks.

Comment: `-avoid_negative_ts 1` gave me a better results. Thanks. But, still there is a slight time margins around the cut. I really need a fast and precise cut, and I hope some one apply my algorithm in ffmpeg. Thanks.

Comment: You might raise it in the ffmpeg forums, since all-frame seeking is supposed to be exact enough.

Comment: If I want to cut at (T2, T2), I want to know in advance where the actual cut will happen (T2, T3).
I assumed that T2 and T3 will be the nearest Keyframes, and tried to implement my algorithm, but didn't work as expected too!